# Cannot create stacked columns in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, stacked-bar-chart

I am trying to create a ggplot2 graph with stacked columns. In my data, I have percentages that go from 0% to 100%, so the y-axis in my graph should not be higher than 100%.

My dataframe looks like this:

```
DF <- data.frame(Area = c("inner", "inner", "inner", "outer",  "outer",  "outer",
                            "inner", "inner", "inner", "outer",  "outer",  "outer"),
                   Period = c("first", "second", "last", "first", "second", "last",
                              "first", "second", "last", "first", "second", "last"),
                   Classification = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A",
                                      "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"),
                   Percentages = c(88.9, 25.2, 100, 0, 55.5, 100,
                                   88.9, 90.9, 100, 90.9, 44.4, 66.7))

head(DF)

   Area Period Classification Percentages
1 inner  first              A        88.9
2 inner second              A        25.2
3 inner   last              A       100.0
4 outer  first              A         0.0
5 outer second              A        55.5
6 outer   last              A       100.0
```

I have tried to create a graph with stacked columns to no avail:

```
ggplot(DF) +
  aes(x = Period, y = Percentages, fill = Classification) + 
  geom_bar(position = "stack", stat = "identity") +
  geom_col() +
  scale_fill_viridis_d(option = "viridis", direction = 1) +
  labs(y = "Frequency of occurrence (%)") +
  theme_minimal() +
  facet_wrap(vars(Area))
```

[image: ggplot graph, unstacked columns]

If anyone knows what I'm doing wrong I would really appreciate the help!

Comment: Are you saying you want them dodged? Because they're clearly stacked as is.... If you want them dodged, change to `geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity")` and remove `geom_col()`, it's just a shorthand for `geom_bar(stat = "identity")`

Comment: Is there perhaps an issue with the data (the way that percentages were calculated) ? It's clear, for example, that the sum of inner/first/A and inner/first/B is more than 100, so the chart is exactly as you would expect, given the numbers. `position_fill` would force the values into the range 0-100% but I think you need to think about whether you are mapping the data appropriately in the first place.

Comment: Why do you call both `geom_bar` and `geom_col`?